# Textarea is too small for the container. Can't even manually enlarge it

Tags: html, css, forms, size, textarea

I have a Problem with a `textarea` in some div-blocks. It just will not accept the full `width` of the block, no matter what I do. I tried giving it a fixed 100% `width`, I tried giving it many more cols, I tried increasing the size manually in the browser, it just will not fill the complete container and I don't get why. It acts, as if there is an invisible col on the right of it, but there isn't.

**Note:**The text part (testwethsfjg.....) before the `textarea` is just to see if the text would be bound on the same boundaries as the `textarea`.

Maybe someone got an idea of what the problem could be. Help would be appreciated.

**CODE**

```css
    .comment-box {
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      margin-left: 200px;
      margin-right: 200px;
      background-color: #e9dac6;
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 3px solid green;
    }
    .comment-box-empty {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .comment-box-full {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: 30px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 25px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .comment-box-top {
      margin: auto;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      background-color: #faebd7;
      border-top-left-radius: 25px;
      border-top-right-radius: 25px;
      border: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .comment-box-top-text {
      font-size: 19px;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 1;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      display: inline;
    }
    .comment-box-content {
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      border: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .comment-box-content-text {
      text-align: justify;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1.25;
    }
```

```html
<div class="comment-box">
  <div class="comment-box-empty">
    <form id="usr_comment">
      <div class="comment-box-top">
        <div class="comment-box-top-text">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" size="10" name="name" />
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" size="15" name="email" />
          <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="show_mail" value="showmail" checked />
          <label for="show_mail">E-Mail für alle Sichtbar anzeigen?</label>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-box-content">
        testwethsfjggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
        <br />
        <textarea></textarea>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Post</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  @{ foreach (var comment in ViewBag.rb1.CommentList) { if (ViewBag.rb1count > 0) {
  <div class="comment-box-full">
    <div class="comment-box-top">
      <div class="comment-box-top-text">
        @comment.Name @comment.Email
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-box-content">
      <div class="comment-box-content-text">
        @comment.Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  } } }
</div>
```

[Screenshot of max width of textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpsPI.jpg)

Comment: Somehow it deleted my greeting line in the beginning. Makes me look like a douche...so there you go. Hi everyone ;-)

Comment: display block and width 100% ?

Comment: try word-break: break-all; on comment-box-content.

Comment: Just giving it a width of 100% works for me..

Comment: I also tried the width: 100%, didn't work here. It makes the max width a 100% that's correct, but that's abouth the width it shows in the screenshot. It just sets this textarea to be this wide from the beginning on.

Comment: @Leo the lion. Didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: @all found the problem. The "min-width" of the textarea had to be a 100%, instead of the "width".

Comment: @Vitriol, happy that you found solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to give `width:100%` to `textarea`, and if not yet, reset `margin/padding`, and to stop re-sizing the `width` I could use `resize:none` or `resize:vertical` depending on your case

here is a sample:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  border: red solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  resize:vertical
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. If I do it, it sets the width of the textarea to the size you see in the screenshot. It will not go further to the right, not even by manually drag and drop with the mouse.

Comment: unfortunately this site is still local. I don't have a webserver yet and it's not finished. But I tried your example, and it didn't work. Even outside of all of the div containers it didn't. Strange.

Comment: @Vitriol just tested your snippet and the `textarea ` is expanding and working perfectly

Comment: Did you leave any of my div tags or classes out? Maybe I overwrite something by using them in the order I do. ... Interesting... on this site here when I run the code snippet, it works fine too.

Comment: thanks for your help. Now I found the problem. I had to set the "min-wdith" of the textarea to 100%, not just the "width". Thank's you helped me alot.

Comment: @Vitriol that's weird because as I showed to you with only `width` was working, unless you were using more code which could be overriding it somehow. So If my answer helped you please make sure you mark it as accepted for future readers know which solution solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can set the width to your textarea, but once the user changes it manually, the css won't work anymore, so you can add a resize:none to ensure the width of the textarea

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 90%;
}
```